# Is there a tool similar to Fences (by Stardock) for Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, gnome, desktop, fences

[Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) is a nice tool, used to organise icons on a Windows desktop.

[image: Fences screenshot]

Does the same thing exist for gnome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Idea #18447: Ubuntu ( GNOME ) has not tool to organize Desktop](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/18447/).
Another reference: [My Must Have Windows 7 Utility: Stardock Fences](http://blogs.zdnet.com/perlow/?p=10992),
refers to the [KDE Folderview](http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/improvements-in-kdes-folderview/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Folders" applet from cairo-dock. Looks similar.

[image: Screenshot of the "Folders" applet]